# Angular loop through JSON with a limited number

Tags: angularjs

Angular has a built-in feature to loop through JSON, for example I can do:

`$scope.users = data.users`

But I want to only loop through a number of users to enhance the performance like:

`$scope.users = data.users[5] to data.users[10]`

How would I be able to do this?

P.S. for pure javascript I can do:

```
for(var i = 5; i <= 11; i++) {
    var user = data.users[i];
}
```

Of course this cannot add `user` to the scope.

Comment: What's about ´$scope.users = data.users.slice(5, 10)´ ?

Comment: @rboe please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method of an array.

```
$scope.users = data.users.slice(5, 11);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter in view

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo : limit.itemCount : limit.startIndex">
```

And in controller set variables that you can easily change to show different items or quantities

```
$scope.limit={
   startIndex :0,
   itemCount : 10
}

$scope.next = function(){
  $scope.limit.startIndex  +=  $scope.limit.itemCount;
}
```

Comment: Oh this one is even better. Thanks.